# Magento2 : Mini cart removeItem is not working

Tags: magento-2.1.7, mini-cart

I have a magento2 live store, that was working properly. But today `mini cart remove item functionality` stopped working.

When I checked in developer mode, I found that the Request Url `/checkout/sidebar/removeItem/` returning `302 found` response status.

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: 302 status is related to requested url is not given properly. can you check url/path?

Comment: Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem" />
</config>
```

Create Vendor/Module/Controller/Sidebar/RemoveItem.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Sidebar;

class RemoveItem extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $itemId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');
        try {
            $this->sidebar->checkQuoteItem($itemId);
            $this->sidebar->removeQuoteItem($itemId);
            return $this->jsonResponse();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code giving me `500 Internal server error`.

Comment: Okay, yeah because in xml file I have given path Vendor/Module/Controller/Checkout/Sidebar/RemoveItem. Make it Vendor\Module\Controller\Checkout\Sidebar\RemoveItem

Comment: Yes I did that already.

Comment: Need to add `__construct` as well in the override file?

Comment: Okay got it. Make path like -  Vendor\Module\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem in di.xml file, Remove 'Checkout' from the path . See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Background:**

In my case, I found out form_key was coming null in parms. Due to which below condition in execute() method

```
if (!$this->getFormKeyValidator()->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/cart/');
        }
```

stops action of removing item from mini cart dropdown.

I also noticed form_key was part of cookies. The only problem was it was not getting sent as Form Data.

**Solution:**

I solved it by creating before plugin for execute() method of class
`Magento\Checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem`

In plugin, I got form_key from cookies and setted it in param and BOOM

```
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class RemoveItem
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function beforeExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem $subject
    ):array
    {
        if (!$this->_request->getParam('form_key')) {
            $formKey = $this->_request->getCookie('form_key', null);
            $this->_request->setParams(['form_key'=>$formKey]);
        }
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue using controller override review code,
Magento\Checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem

```
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Sidebar;
    class RemoveItem extends 
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem
        {
            public function execute()
            {
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $resultJson = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory')->create();
                $itemId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');
                try {
                    $this->sidebar->checkQuoteItem($itemId);
                    $this->sidebar->removeQuoteItem($itemId);
                    return $resultJson->setData(true);
                } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                    return $resultJson->setData($e->getMessage());
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->logger->critical($e);
                    return $resultJson->setData($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```